# Writing Excel using maps in groovy

Tags: java, groovy, treemap

I am trying to write an excel file using maps in groovy.
In java i am entering the values in my map as given below

```
  //writing data in the map   
Map < String, Object[] > empinfo = new TreeMap < String, Object[] >();
  empinfo.put( "1", new Object[] {"EMP ID", "EMP NAME", "DESIGNATION" });
  empinfo.put( "2", new Object[] {"", "Gopal", "Technical Manager" });
  empinfo.put( "7", new Object[] {"tp02", "Manisha", "Proof Reader" });
  empinfo.put( "4", new Object[] {"tp03", "", "Technical Writer" });
  empinfo.put( "5", new Object[] {"tp04", "Satish", "Technical Writer" });
  empinfo.put( "6", new Object[] {"tp05", "Krishna", "" });

  //Iterate over data and write to sheet
  Set < String > keyid = empinfo.keySet();
  int rowid = 0;
  for (String key : keyid)
  {
     row = spreadsheet.createRow(rowid++);
     Object [] objectArr = empinfo.get(key);
     int cellid = 0;
     for (Object obj : objectArr)
     {
        Cell cell = row.createCell(cellid++);
        cell.setCellValue((String)obj);
     }
  }
```

How can this be done in groovy?
I am new to groovy and any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You should be able to do exactly what you are doing... what's the question? Rewrite this in idiomatic groovy? What have you tried? Where are you having problems?

Comment: Yes i want to write this in groovy. Currently I am trying something like this
 `def empinfo = [:];   
empinfo.put("EMP ID", "EMP NAME", "DESIGNATION" );   empinfo.put("", "Gopal", "Technical Manager");   
empinfo.put("tp02", "Manisha", "Proof Reader" );   
empinfo.put("tp03", "", "Technical Writer" );   
empinfo.put("tp04", "Satish", "Technical Writer" );   
empinfo.put("tp05", "Krishna", "" );`

Comment: I am getting the following error 
  `Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.LinkedHashMap.put() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [EMP ID, EMP NAME, DESIGNATION]
Possible solutions: put(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object), put(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object), wait(), any(), sort(), dump()
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.LinkedHashMap.put() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [.....
`

Answer (score 1):

You get `groovy.lang.MissingMethodException` because groovy does not support such array declaration syntax.

[Groovy array declaration](http://grails.asia/groovy-array-manipulation-examples)

[Groovy map declaration](http://grails.asia/groovy-map-tutorial)

Here is how you can declare TreeMap

```
def empinfo = new TreeMap<String, Object[]>();

empinfo["1"] = ["EMP ID", "EMP NAME", "DESIGNATION"] as Object[];
empinfo["2"] = ["", "Gopal", "Technical Manager"] as Object[];
empinfo["7"] = ["tp02", "Manisha", "Proof Reader"] as Object[];
empinfo["4"] = ["tp03", "", "Technical Writer"] as Object[];
empinfo["5"] = ["tp04", "Satish", "Technical Writer"] as Object[];
empinfo["6"] = ["tp05", "Krishna", ""] as Object[];
```

or

```
TreeMap empinfo = [
    "1": ["EMP ID", "EMP NAME", "DESIGNATION"] as Object[],
    "2": ["", "Gopal", "Technical Manager"] as Object[],
    "7": ["tp02", "Manisha", "Proof Reader"] as Object[],
    "4": ["tp03", "", "Technical Writer"] as Object[],
    "5": ["tp04", "Satish", "Technical Writer"] as Object[],
    "6": ["tp05", "Krishna", ""] as Object[]
];
```

Answer (score 0):

There are more than one way to skin a cat:

```groovy
// writing data in the map
def empinfo = [
    "1" : ["EMP ID", "EMP NAME", "DESIGNATION"],
    "2" : ["", "Gopal", "Technical Manager"],
    "3" : ["tp02", "Manisha", "Proof Reader"],
    "4" : ["tp03", "", "Technical Writer"],
    "5" : ["tp04", "Satish", "Technical Writer"],
    "6" : ["tp05", "Krishna", ""]
]

short rowid = 0
empinfo.each { key, value ->
    row = spreadsheet.createRow(rowid++)
    short cellid = 0
    value.each { item ->
        def cell = row.createCell(cellid++)
        cell.setCellValue(item)
    }
}
```

It is up to you how much "Groovyness" you would like to have.

Comment: I changed the data type of `rowid` and `cellid` to `short`, because POI doesn't accept ints.